# Text before bullet in unordered list

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

Is it possible when creating a html unordered list `<ul>` to add text before the bullet?
The result i am trying to achieve would look similar to this:

T1 * more text1

T2 * more text2

T3 * more text3

where * are the bullets in the ul.I kept searching pretty much everywhere but i can't seem to find anything and have no idea from where to start.
I tried to add text before the li, but the result is not what I expected:

T1

text1

T2

text2

T3

text3

Comment: That depends what kind of text you like to enter before the bullets. But you should probably create custom bullets and not use the default ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `:before` pseudo here would restrict the use of different text. Wrapping the text which you need with some tag before the bullets will make it easier to give appropriate classes to it.

Check this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mask2486/ujo6Lnwp/) for working example.

Comment: Not entirely true...CSS counters can be used with a pseudo-element. See my answer.

Comment: Didn't knew about CSS counters, but it's still restricting it to change the count alone. I would encourage using CSS counters if the preceeding text remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy way to do it using CSS. First, remove the current bullets:

```
li{
list-style-type: none;
}
```

Then, before every list item, add the content you want to add, followed by a bullet. Like so:

```
ul li:before{
content: 'hi \2022';
}
```

Hope this helps!

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mgqbdqgr/)**

Comment: thanks, but as I posted in the example, I have different text for each list item. Perhaps adding an id to each li and changing the css with some jquery would do the trick. (i forgot to mention, data is taken from server with ajax)

Comment: `:before` pseudo will restrict usage to same text before each list item.

Comment: also list-style:none should go to UL

Answer (score 1):

You can do this CSS counters and a pseudo-element.

[**CSS Counters @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters)

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: section;
}
li:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "T"counter(section)". ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some Text</li>
  <li>Some Text</li>
  <li>Some Text</li>
  <li>Some Text</li>
  <li>Some Text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try display inline for both the text and the li ? i hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <span style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">Hi!</span><li> Hello</li>
  <span style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">Hi!</span><li> Hello</li>
  <span style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">Hi!</span><li> Hello</li>
  <span style="float: left;margin-right: 20px;">Hi!</span><li> Hello</li>
</ul>
```

[http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPbgmR](http://LINK)